# Which is more grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

I'm having some problems determining which of the following is more grammatically correct:

> The season that I like the best is Winter

or

> Winter is the season that I like the best

I know that both are technically correct, but when would you use one over the other?

Comment: They are both syntactically correct, except seasons do not need to be capitalised. Also the _that_ is not mandatory. This flows better in my opinion: _The winter season is my favourite._ or _My favourite season is winter_ depending on what deadrat just said

Comment: This is a matter of style. What do you want to emphasize -- winter or the seasons?

Comment: There is no such thing as "more grammatically correct". Something is either grammatically correct, or it isn't. You cannot be 81% grammatically correct or 32% grammatically correct. All you can do is speak English, or fail at it. And both sentences in question are quite obviously English.

Answer (score 3):

They are both grammatically correct. Since you're using the linking verb *to be*, it doesn't matter whether *winter* or *the season* is the subject. Thus, the order doesn't change the meaning, only the nuances, like timing and emphasis.

For example, if you were speaking this sentence, and you wanted to create suspense, you might choose the order, *The season I like best is winter*. But if you want your audience to immediately know what you're talking about, then you might say *Winter is the season I like best*.

Answer (score -2):

*The season that I like the best is Winter* is more grammatically correct. Also, ktm5124 omitted the definite article *the* between the words *like* and *best*. (But I might be wrong.)

Comment: I bet you are a good proofreader!  Yes, the OP did include "the," but ktm5124 omitted it.  That's okay, "the" is optional there.

Comment: Why is it more grammatically correct?